# Ошибка с "нарезкой" string kotlin

Tags: android, строки, kotlin

При выборе файла через `onActivityResult()` я хочу "нарезать" его на куски. Для этого я считываю его байты:

```
val fileUri = data.data!!
val string = fileUri.let { uri -> contentResolver.openInputStream(uri).use { it!!.readBytes() } }
```

и провожу "нарезку":

```
val partSize = 10000
val partsCount = if (size.rem(partSize).toInt() == 0) {
    size.div(partSize).toInt()
} else {
    size.div(partSize).toInt() + 1
}

for (i in 0 until partsCount) {

val slicedString: ByteArray = if ((i + 1) * partSize < i * partSize + size.rem(partSize).toInt()) {
    string.slice(i * partSize..(i + 1) * partSize).toByteArray()
} else {
    string.slice(i * partSize..i * partSize + size.rem(partSize).toInt()).toByteArray()
}

}
```

а теперь собственно проблема: размер файла `127036` а у меня приложение падает с ошибкой:

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: toIndex (127037) is greater than size (127036)
```

Вопрос - откуда еще один байт взялся, и как его убрать? Может это какой-то пробел или невидимый символ, который нужно убирать через `trim()`? Если брать обычный вывод в консоль идексов для нарезки то все нормально:

```
if ((i + 1) * partSize < i * partSize + size.rem(partSize).toInt()) {
Timber.i((i * partSize..(i + 1) * partSize).toString())
} else {
Timber.i((i * partSize..i * partSize + size.rem(partSize).toInt()).toString())
}
```

Допускаю что проблема где-то в `size.rem(partSize).toInt()`. Округлить не получается, потому что передается long а в документации есть только double/int. Есть так же идея сдвинуть на один бит:

```
size.rem(partSize).shr(1).toInt()
```

но не уверен что это правильное решение.

Comment: какого типа переменная size? Есть подозрение, что если в else в первом примере сделать string.slice(i * partSize..i * partSize - 1 + size.rem(partSize).toInt()).toByteArray() то проблема решится

Comment: @СпицкоДмитрий, тип long

Comment: а почему бы просто не использовать [chunked](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/chunked.html) ?

Comment: @IR42, а разве чанк подойдет для байтов?

Comment: Можно так `val l: List<List<Byte>> = byteArrayOf(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9).asIterable().chunked(2)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Простой тест показывает где именно ошибка.

```
val i = 1
val partSize = 7
val size = "1234567890".length

println(i * partSize..i * partSize + size.rem(partSize).toInt())
// 7..10

"1234567890".slice(7..10)
// Exception
```

`slice` вырезает интервал ОТ-ДО включительно. Соответственно границу ДО нужно высчитывать не забывая, что значение длины строки не является ее последним индексом.

Верным мне видится такой код:

```
val slicedString: ByteArray = if ((i + 1) * partSize < size) {
  string.slice(i * partSize..(i + 1) * partSize).toByteArray()
} else {
  string.slice(i * partSize..(size - 1)).toByteArray()
}
```